# Mootools New Element 'Class' bug in IE 7 and 8

Tags: internet-explorer, mootools

In mootools 1.3 the following code produces an error when viewing in Internet Explorer 7 and 8:

```
new Element('div', {class: 'thumbBox'});
```

the error is as follows:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

That error points to the start of the word "class" in the above code.

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class` is a reserved keyword in IE, put it in speech marks / quotes.

```
new Element("div", {
    "class": "foo",
    id: "bar"
});
```

you can actually write that as:

```
new Element("div#bar.foo");
```